# Can I disable the image emoticons in the Chrome Hangout app?

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, google-hangouts, emoticons

First, I don't mean stopping the conversion of the text I type [like this question asks](https://superuser.com/questions/943015/how-do-i-make-google-hangouts-stop-converting-text-to-emoji). 
Second, by "Chrome Hangout app", I mean [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl?hl=en), the external window, running in Microsoft Windows.

I hate these emoticons therefore I don't use them. However, other people do. I want to disable the little pictures of smiling yellow blobs that Hangout uses (as well as any other non-smiley ones). I'm fine seeing either the unicode version or the text shortcut (`☺` or `:)`).

Were I using the web version, I could just use a chrome addon or a user style but for the standalone app, I have no idea. The process seems to be a child of chrome in the task manager but chrome plugins don't seem to affect it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you just go to options and uncheck the text to emoji.
This disables all emojis though, so Idk about only smileys.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No that checkbox only handle the text you type, as I said in my first sentence.

Comment: Oh, I thought it converted all text in hangouts. My Bad.